# How to set the colors for inactiveTrackColor & inactiveThumbColor for SwitchListTile via ThemeData in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, material-design

I can set the inactive colors for the SwitchListTile where used throughout the app, however, it would be a lot simpler to set this in the app theme (as I have multiple custom themes).

However, I noticed these color values can't be passed into SwitchThemeData, and wonder if I am missing something?

E.g. I can set the colors in the individual SwitchListTile widgets.

```
    return SwitchListTile(
      inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey,
      inactiveThumbColor: AppColors.lightGrey,...)
```

But want to define the inactive colors in the ThemeData class.

```
ThemeData(
  switchTheme: SwitchThemeData(
    thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(AppColors.tealPrimary),
    trackColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(AppColors.tealDarkest),
    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(AppColors.lightGrey),
//// MISSING INACTIVE PROPERTIES HERE?
  ),
...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem,I tried this,and it's worked.

https://m2.material.io/design/interaction/states.html#usage
The color from MaterialState.selected  means trackColor of SwitchListTile,and the other color means activeTrackColor of SwitchListTile.

```
    switchTheme: SwitchThemeData(
      trackColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected))
          return Colors.grey;
        return Colors.green;
      }),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**